# When does validate method get called in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a model `StudentProductRelationship`. I am adding a custom validator

`validate :validate_primary_product , :if => "!primary_product"`

The method is

```
def validate_primary_tag 
  unless StudentProductRelationship.exists?(:primary_product => true, :student_id => student_id)
    errors.add(:base,"There is no primary product associated to product")
  else
  end
end
```

`primary_product` is a boolean field. I want to validate presence of at least one true `primary_product` for `student_id`. The problem is if I have an `StudentProductRelationship` object say `spr` with `primary_product = true`. If I do `spr.update_attributes(primary_product: false)`. The validation does not raise an error because `StudentProductRelationship.exists?(:primary_product => true, :student_id => student_id)` exists beacuse `spr` still exists in db with `primary_product = true`. How do i surpass this?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't `validates_presence_of :primary_product, scope: :student_id` work for your?

Comment: No. Not presence I need it to be `true`. This would handle `false` as well right?